# mac downgrade node version still show last version

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

Im trying to downgrade my node version so I run on terminal on mac

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 9.10.0
```

then I try to check the version and it still as last version

> npm -v
>    => 5.6
>
> node -v => v10.11.0

in addition when I run the commands above I get this errors
[image]

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/5706630)

Comment: Try running `type node` to see if you have aliased it, hashed it, or made a function of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use https://github.com/creationix/nvm for get several versions in your PC